# Determining whether values between rows match for certain columns

Tags: r

I am working with some observation data and have run into a bit of an issue beyond my current capabilities. I surveyed different polygons (the column "PolygonID" in the screenshot) for lizards two times during a survey season. I want to determine the total search effort (shown in the column "Effort") for each individual polygon within each survey round. Problem is, the software I was using to collect the data sometimes creates unnecessary repeats for polygons within a survey round. There is an example of this in the screenshot for the rows with PolygonID P3.

Most of the time it does not affect the effort calculations because the start and end time for the rows (the fields used to calculate effort) are the same, and I know how to filter the dataset so it only shows one line per polygon per survey, but I have reason to be concerned there might be some lines where the software glitched and assigned incorrect start and end times for one of the repeat lines. Is there a way I can test whether start and end time match for any such repeats with R, rather than manually going through all the data?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Does the glitch occur only for the repeats?  Or can it also occur for the first appearance of a polygon in a survey?  Indeed, what is the point of reference for the "correct" times?

Comment: Please share some reproducible data as code, not a pictures. `dput()` is the nicest way to recreate an R object, use `dput(your_data[1:5, c("select", "relevant", "columns")])` to share the first 5 rows of selected relevant columns---choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, only for repeats. I would have to examine the data to know which line was correct but as a starting point, I need to know if there are cases when Start_Time and End_Time don't match between repeat lines. As for the code- I am not sure what you mean.